# What can i do? am having problems embedding fonts into my code

Tags: fonts

So am working on a new website, and have been trying some fonts which include the Montserrat-Black but it doesn't seem to work for my code.....i got the code from google fonts but it doesn't work on my website.
please what can i do?

I tried the code from google fonts but it still didn't work

Comment: Share the codes you already write